# Android: Search button instead of Enter for EditText

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

I have the following for Edit Text:

```
    <EditText
         android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/myBookSearchEditTextId"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="@color/black" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Why I still see on the keyboard the Enter key instead of the Search Key?

I found something - it seems like when using softkeyboard it has a porblem...
As found in the web - maybe needs to get InputmethodManager in the OnClick on the edittext:

```
...Onclick(...)
{
    InputmethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0 );
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on device or in emulator ? What is requestFocus here ?

Comment: which api level are you using?

Comment: Testing on a device. When testing on a device - does it matter which API level the project is set to? It is set to Min API level 8.

Comment: BTW - on the device - if I enter the search in the Android Market I see the search button as supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. editTx.setImeActionLabel("Search",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH); instead of in layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

My Search icon didn't show up till I add the `inputType`.

Both of these are require:

> android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

and

> android:inputType="text"